Running headless chrome on EC2 g4dn instance. Not able to output chrome://gpu
I have been trying to get the headless chrome / google chrome to run on EC2 instance with a GPU (g4dn.xlarge).
The purpose of it would be to stream video game application.
I followed this article to setup the instance with the necessary GPU driver and packages.
https://dev.to/mirzabilal/how-to-enable-hardware-acceleration-on-chrome-chromium-puppeteer-on-aws-in-headless-mode-50hd
This is a step in the article where the chrome://gpu page is opened on the headless chrome and the screenshot of it gets output as output.pdf.
  google-chrome-stable --headless --use-gl=angle \
    --use-angle=gl-egl --use-cmd-decoder=passthrough \
    --print-to-pdf=output.pdf 'chrome://gpu'

The problem I'm facing is that instead of opening chrome://gpu it opens up chrome://new-tab-page
I have attached snip of the pdf for reference.
I did encounter a few errors when I run the above command. Here's the log
[4175:4269:0911/053816.001929:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(576)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get: object_path= /org/freedesktop/UPower: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.UPower was not provided by any .service files
[4175:4269:0911/053816.002261:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(576)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.UPower.GetDisplayDevice: object_path= /org/freedesktop/UPower: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.UPower was not provided by any .service files
[4175:4269:0911/053816.002550:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(576)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.UPower.EnumerateDevices: object_path= /org/freedesktop/UPower: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.UPower was not provided by any .service files
30025 bytes written to file output.pdf
[4214:4214:0911/053819.617095:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(224)] SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
[4214:4214:0911/053819.618405:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(224)] SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.

I'm quite clueless on what to do next. I'd really appreciate the help in figuring it out
I tried running the chromium version as well. It has the same issue.
I ensured that the driver is installed and running using the nvidia-smi command.
The Ubuntu version is 24.04, the Nvidia driver version is 560.35.03. Google Chrome 128.0.6613.119
I used Claude 3.5 Sonnet quite a lot to figure out a solution for this, but no luck there either

Hmm, yeah. It's been evolving so rapidly.
I decided to try my luck with puppeteer + Node, and it did the job.
I'll check to see if --headless=old will make a difference

@KJ,
google-chrome-stable --headless=old --use-gl=angle \     --use-angle=gl-egl --use-cmd-decoder=passthrough \     --print-to-pdf=output.pdf 'chrome://gpu' 
Although It worked it threw quite a few scary warnings. However, the pdf clearly shows the chrome://gpu page now.
Could you please post this as the answer? I'll mark it as the accepted answer.
I really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Currently from versions 122 upwards Chrome/Chromium cores are evolving away from using one executable model into two.
One designed for Browsing with Puppeteer and one for simplified headless tasks.
The first move was to add a --headless=new and --headless=old switch, this worked well upto version 127.
Then default the new behaviour to the be the default overriding the --headless behaviours, this worked well upto version 127.
The aim is to remove the headless switch for basic tasks such as screenshot or PDF printing.
So going forward there is a core executable specifically called chrome-headless-shell that works in a different graphics headless context.
It would in simplest cases be used as save input to an absolute addressed file,
Chrome-headless-shell --print-to-pdf=drive:/folder/output.pdf URL://remote/local
For now the current shell versions are listed in a way they can be auto downloaded and I have shown a windows solution at Headless Chrome to print pdf
Shown here as overlapping questions tend to be deleted.
Helper script (download.cmd). Replace the 2 win32 with win64 or adapt script for mac/linux OS variants if you wish.
set "download=chrome-headless-shell-win32.zip"
set "variant=win32/%download%"

curl -o LATEST_RELEASE_STABLE.txt https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/LATEST_RELEASE_STABLE
set /p version=<LATEST_RELEASE_STABLE.txt
curl -O https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/%version%/%variant%
tar -xf %download%

The URL in this case is less conventional as not file:/// or https:// but an internal chrome://invocation (GPU report) thus may not work with simplified headless executable.
However the OP Qile has found the switch for accessing internal chrome addresses is
--allow-chrome-scheme-url 'chrome://gpu'
I tested with headless shell where it did not work HOWEVER Qile found it did work with google-chrome-stable! So this may be the best future usage?
google-chrome-stable --headless --use-gl=angle --use-angle=gl-egl --use-cmd-decoder=passthrough --print-to-pdf=output.pdf --allow-chrome-scheme-url 'chrome://gpu'

As an interim measure, until fully test out migration, (there are 3 executable streams for now!). You can rollback a working system to legacy behaviour, by switch --headless to old.
google-chrome-stable --headless=old --use-gl=angle --use-angle=gl-egl --use-cmd-decoder=passthrough --print-to-pdf=path/output.pdf 'chrome://gpu'

I suggest that you double-check with the chromium teams what system is to be used in this case for the future as old headless is likely to be removed soon.

Yeah, I received the warning that the old headless would be deprecated soon. Need to figure out an alternate

Was just going through the documentation on chrome headless and stumbled upon this. It mentions the need to use --allow-chrome-scheme-url flag to access chrome://**** pages.
I tested it and it seems to work.

Here's the command for ref
google-chrome-stable --headless --use-gl=angle --use-angle=gl-egl --use-cmd-decoder=passthrough --print-to-pdf=output.pdf --allow-chrome-scheme-url 'chrome://gpu'

If it's not too much trouble, please add it into your answer. Should fit in well with the rest of the stuff you've described

Looks Perfect! Thanks a lot.
